# Как отследить запуск (регистрацию) приемника (BroadcastReceiver)

Tags: android, broadcast-receiver

Как правило регистрация приемника (BroadcastReceiver) осуществляется в момент создания Activity, отмена регистрации  - при удалении Activity.
Хочу этот процесс привязать к нажатию кнопки, то есть:
Нажимаем кнопку -  запускается сервис и приемник.
Когда сервис присылает сообщение, приемник отключаем.
Проблема в том, что каждое нажатие кнопки регистрирует новый приемник, если "старый" ещё не отключен.
Для устранения двойной (тройной и т.д.) регистрации приемника ввёл дополнительную переменную lReceiverOn, содержимое которой проверяю перед регистрацией.

```
public void clickLayout(View view) {
 startService(new Intent(this, MyServiceFlash.class).putExtra("Mode", 3));  //Запуск сервиса, откуда ждем сообщений
 if (! lReceiverOn) {
   LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
      mReceiver, new IntentFilter("SrvIntent")); // регистрируем приемник сообщений из сервиса
 lReceiverOn = true; // переменная контроля запуска приемника
 }
    ...
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() { // приемник сообщений из сервиса
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ...
 LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).unregisterReceiver(mReceiver); // отмена регистрации
    lReceiverOn=false;
    }
  };
```

Вопрос: можно ли обойтись без этой переменной, определить, что приемник запущен? 
По наивности пробовал (mReceiver != null), не работает. Других методов найти не смог.

Comment: Опишите задачу. Судя по описанию, вы что-то не то придумываете. Зачем вам отключать приемник после получения? По коду: проверяйте mRecevier!=null при клике. Если null инициализируйте его, регистрируйте. В onReceive обnullяйте его.

Comment: Зачем вы делаете ресивер анонимным, вынесите его в отдельный класс и будет вам счастье. Создаете его в `onCreate()` и регистрируйте при нажатии

Comment: Задача следующая:
Из Активности запускается Сервис, который может быть остановлен нажатием кнопки.
Есть ещё кнопка – «остановить сервис через заданное время».
Если её нажать, в Сервисе включается таймер и в Активности надо отловить момент, когда таймер остановится.
Может, конечно, это экономия на спичках, но я не хочу регистрировать приемник при запуске приложения, так как он может и не понадобиться. Поэтому регистрация приемника происходит только при нажатии кнопки таймера. 
**mRecevier!=null** не работает, точнее, всегда дает «истину» 
Насчет анонимности... разве mRecevier не имя?

Comment: У вас mReceiver инициализируется в месте объявления поля класса. Уберите оттуда, инициализируйте его в clickLayout. ЗЫ. Решаемая вами задача смысла не имеет. Кроме того, вы пытаетесь добавить связанность компонентов, которой при использовании activity-recevier-service пытаются избежать. Что будет если сервис стопнут из другого места, или что будет если это будет сам android, а потом сам перезапустит его, что если для старта сервиса не хватает ресурсов? Активити принимает сообщения, об остальном ей знать не обязательно.

Comment: Иными словами, не существует специальных методов, позволяющих определить регистрацию приемника. Либо создавать и изменять дополнительную переменную, либо самостоятельно обнулять BroadcastReceiver-переменную. Наверное ни к чему  заморачиваться, просто стандартно регистрировать приемник при запуске Активити